# createPrintDocumentAdapter replacement

Tags: android, printing

I get a warning when building my android project that "createPrintDocumentAdapter" has been deprecated. It is a method on WebView.

I have been looking but have been unable to find what the intended replacement is. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per the [Javadoc for createPrintDocumentAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#createPrintDocumentAdapter()):

> **This method was deprecated in API level 21.**
>
> Use [createPrintDocumentAdapter(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#createPrintDocumentAdapter(java.lang.String)) which requires user to provide a print document name.

Therefore if you need to support < API 21, continue to use the current method, but on API 21+ devices, use `createPrintDocumentAdapter(String)`

Answer (score 6):

Based on the accepted answer and the [official example](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html#print-job):

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void createWebPrintJob(Context context, WebView webView) {

    // Get a PrintManager instance
    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    String jobName = context.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

    // Get a print adapter instance
    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName);
    }
    else {
        printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
    }

    // Create a print job with name and adapter instance

    PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
            new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());

    // Save the job object for later status checking
    mPrintJobs.add(printJob);

}
```

Comment: mPrintJobs what's that?

Comment: @Aks4125 add this :         List<PrintJob> mPrintJobs = printManager.getPrintJobs();

Comment: @ArbazAlam Actually, mine is just `private static ArrayList<PrintJob> mPrintJobs = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Why do we need the check for SDK_INT >= LOLLIPOP? I guess when we compile with an SDK newer than LOLLIPOP and run it on a device with LOLLIPOP or older, the jobName is just ignored? Am I wrong?